# nativescript-image-zoom not working in angular

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, zooming

I'm trying to load [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-image-zoom) plugin in Angular 7.1.1

getting an error that says...

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Could not load view
>   for: ImageZoom.Error: Could not find module 'nativescript-image-zoom'.

Loading the following in main.ts

```
import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
registerElement('ImageZoom', () => require('nativescript-image-zoom').ImageZoom);
```

in the html:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ImageZoom src="~/img/icon.jpg" maxZoom="5" minZoom="2"</ImageZoom>
</StackLayout>
```

anyone else have the same issue?

Comment: I think you should register element in modules.ts

Comment: i tried that...still throws the same error

Comment: have you added that package? tns plugin add nativescript-image-zoom

Comment: ...yes i did add the package

Comment: which platform are you testing? I have created a playground https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Mj2RQC and on ios it is hsowing error  `WARN: Objective-C class name "UIScrollViewDelegateImpl" is already in use - using "UIScrollViewDelegateImpl1" instead.`

Comment: Based on the error it looks like the plugin was never included in bundle. Did you try a clean build after adding the plugin?

Comment: i just did a clean build of my project and for some reason when its preparing the plugins nativescript-image-zoom is not included...any reason why?

Comment: is it possible for you to share your package.json? Have you tried npn i with this package.json in separate folder?